# Submit button not giving any response after adding on the "required" attribute onto the modal form

Tags: javascript, php, html

After adding on the required attribute, my submit button does not have any response. When the textbox is empty after pressing the submit button, the validation occurs but the button does nothing and does not have any response. The submit button only works finely after when the required attribute is removed. The below shows my html form:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Manage store</title>

        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Varela+Round">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/form.css" />

    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post" action="store.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <div id="addStoreModal" class="modal fade">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Add Stores</h4>      
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">   
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Store location</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="storeloc" id="storeloc" class="form-control" required/>  
                                </div> 
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Status</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="status">
                                        <option value="Active">Active</option>
                                        <option value="Inactive">Inactive</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">
                                  <button type="submit" name="addStore" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div id="deleteStoreModal" class="modal fade">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Employee</h4> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <p>Are you sure you want to delete these Records?</p>
                                <p class="text-warning"><small>This action cannot be undone.</small></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">
                                <input type="submit" name="deleteStore" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div id="editStoreModal" class="modal fade">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">                    
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Stores</h4>                    
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Store location</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="editstoreloc" class="form-control"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Status</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="editstatus">
                                        <option value="Active">Active</option>
                                        <option value="Inactive">Inactive</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">
                                   <button type="submit" name="editStore" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>




              <div id="storeExistModal" class="modal fade">
                  <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h4 class="modal-title">Store exist</h4>
                                </div>  
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="submit" name="existStore" class="btn btn-primary">Ok</button>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>
             </div>  
           </div>           

        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: try to use input tag instead button `<input type="submit" name="existStore" class="btn btn-primary" value="Ok" />`

Comment: Did tried before but still the same issue

Comment: Can you show your javascript validation code?

Comment: Bytheway, there are two submits button. Can be that the problem